# FBLoginView calling delegate multiple times to Fetch User Info

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook on many views inside my app. So I have a FBLoginView that i instantiated in AppDelegate. I subview it in view-one and load its info in view-one. In dealloc I remove it from superview.

When i move to view2 I subview it there as wel. When I was using sdk on every subview its delegates were getting called and I was fetching the userinfo to display in view2. Now I updated to sdk3.7 and now delegates are not getting called on subview unless the button getted clicked to logout and re-login again.

I want to know how to get userinfo via FBLoginView multiple times, without logout and re-login again.

Comment: Wel i have got the answer. If someone need to fetch userinfo again in another view using same session and loginview do let me know.

Comment: How about you answer your own question, and accept it?  :-)

Comment: Then reviewers will simply tag this question in close line.